# How to use fill_between utilizing the where parameter

Tags: python, matplotlib

So following a tutorial, I tried to create a graph using the following code:

```
time_values = [i for i in range(1,100)]
execution_time = [random.randint(0,100) for i in range(1,100)]
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = plt.subplot()
threshold=[.8 for i in range(len(execution_time))]
ax1.plot(time_values, execution_time)
ax1.margins(x=-.49, y=0)
ax1.fill_between(time_values,execution_time, 1,where=(execution_time>1), color='r', alpha=.3)
```

This did not work as I got an error saying I could not compare a list and an int. 
However, I then tried:

```
ax1.fill_between(time_values,execution_time, 1)
```

And that gave me a graph with all area in between the execution time and the y=1 line, filled in. Since I want the area above the y=1 line filled in, with the area below left un-shaded, I created a list called threshold, and populated it with 1 so that I could recreate the comparison. However,

```
ax1.fill_between(time_values,execution_time, 1,where=(execution_time>threshold)
```

and

```
ax1.fill_between(time_values,execution_time, 1)
```

create the exact same graph, even though the execution times values do go beyond 1.

I am confused for two reasons:
firstly, in the tutorial I was watching, the teacher was able to successfully compare a list and an integer within the fill_between function, why was I not able to do this?
Secondly, why is the where parameter not identifying the regions I want to fill? Ie, why is the graph shading in the areas between the y=1 and the value of the execution time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is mainly due the use of python lists instead of numpy arrays. Clearly you *could* use lists, but then you need to use them throughout the code.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

time_values = list(range(1,100))
execution_time = [np.random.randint(0,100) for _ in range(len(time_values))]
threshold = 50


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(time_values, execution_time)
ax.fill_between(time_values, execution_time, threshold,
                where= [e > threshold for e in execution_time], 
                color='r', alpha=.3)

ax.set_ylim(0,None)
plt.show()
```

Better is the use of numpy arrays throughout. It's not only faster, but also easier to code and understand.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

time_values = np.arange(1,100)
execution_time = np.random.randint(0,100, size=len(time_values))
threshold = 50


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(time_values, execution_time)
ax.fill_between(time_values,execution_time, threshold,
                where=(execution_time > threshold), color='r', alpha=.3)

ax.set_ylim(0,None)
plt.show()
```